# Java Color Chooser panel in main window?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to add a HSV color chart to the window of my application. I'm aware of the color chooser offered by Java, but i would like to have the chart integrated in my own window instead of opening it a new window. Is there a way to add one of the panels from the color chooser directly to my window, or is there a way to create one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
    AbstractColorChooserPanel hsvPanel = colorChooser.getChooserPanels()[1];
    frame.add(hsvPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I was able to pull the HSV Panel out by accessing the element at 1 in the getChooserPanels for the default JColorChooser.

Although this might not be ideal considering the implementation of the JChooserPanel could change the ordering.

Comment: Have you tried this with different look and feels and/or multiple platforms, the HSV panel may not always be the second panel...

Comment: Yes you must be careful with this as I said the code relies heavily on the implementation. You might want to look at possibly initializing a JColorChooser with your own implementation of an AbstractColorChooserPanel which uses an HSV Model, unfortunately the oracle implementations of these are hidden from the user and proprietary.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input guys, i see the potential problem. This is just going to be a personal tool however, and your solution works just fine for now :)